# How do I pivot my table the way i want to?

Tags: sql

I wrangled my data through python but I am now asked to do the same in SQL. I'm trying to pivot the data in the picture below so the values in 'naam_installation' are the columns, the column 'value' will be the different values and the 'Woning', 'Klant', 'Soort_woning' and 'tijd' will be separate columns. I want it to be like the second screenshot (datetime = tijd).

SQL table to be changed

[image]

How I want to data done in python.

[image]

Comment: You probably shouldn't be performing PIVOT in SQL - it's a _presentation layer concern_, not a data-layer concern.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots of code and data. **Post your actual code and data**. Use SQLFiddle if possible.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)